# Dockerizar proyect ASP.NET 6

Tags: asp.net-core, docker

Tengo una API desarrollada en ASP.Net el desarrollo lo he realizado en Visual Studio 2022, mi intención era una vez finalizado desplegar un contendor Docker.
Durante el desarrollo no ha habido problemas para depurar desde Docker, pero ahora quería ya desplegar el contenedor, pero no me funciona a no ser que arranque el proyecto depurando desde Visual Studio, cuando se para la depuración aunque el contenedor esté en marcha deja de funcionar
Cabe decir que he habilitado https con un certificado auto-firmado:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "connectionStrings": {
    "defaultConnection": "Data Source=VSE\\TEST;Initial Catalog=Scee;User ID=adminTest;Password=11111+;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
 
  "LCOEMServiceSettings": {
    "ServiceName": "LCOEMService",
    "MachineName": "."
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndpointDefaults": {
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    },
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "https://*:40155"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "Certs/aspnetapp.pfx",
        "Password": "121212"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Y mi .dockerIgnore es este:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 40155

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["VAL.API/VAL.API.csproj", "VAL.API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "VAL.API/VAL.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/VAL.API"
RUN dotnet build "VAL.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "VAL.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "VAL.API.dll"]
```

El certificado está en un directorio del proyecto:

> /certs

y parece que se está copiando correctamente al contenedor.

¿Me podéis echar una mano, por favor?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Conoces cómo revisar los logs de un contenedor de Docker?

Comment: Desde el mismo docker entiendo, el problema es que la detener la depuración de Visual Studio la API del contenedor empieza a rechazar las peticiones.

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que necesitas iniciar el contenedor docker. Intenta con los siguientes ejemplos: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-run-command-with-examples Ya si en caso, luego de iniciar, te lanza error, toca ver los logs. ¡Saludos y que sigan los éxitos en el desarollo!

Comment: No si el contenedor permanece iniciado cuando detengo la depuración y si lo arranco desde Docker Desktop, arranca pero ni funciona ni deja log ni nada

Comment: Veo que el comportamiento, es el mismo en un proyecto nuevo, no es cosa de mi API, algo no estoy haciendo bien.